# How to reduce hang time of failed DB connection

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a java web application that connects to a MSSQL 2005 database using Hibernate.

As the connnection to the DB from my application is not critical I wanted to test how the application behaved when the database was unavailable.

When I stop the SQL services and run through a part of the web application that runs queries on the database, my application hangs for about 30 seconds that then continues to function as normal.

As expected the error in the logs is:

```
2012-08-13 16:33:04,974 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2012-08-13 16:33:04,974 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] The TCP/IP connection to the host bonnie.uk, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
```

Does anyone know how I can reduce the hangtime of the application?

Thanks

Shaw

Comment: Your driver should support something similar to a `ConnectionTimeout` property. I'm not overly familiar with JDBC or what the rest of your framework is composed of, but [it looks like it's supported generally](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005099.connection.timeout.in.jdbc.html). Second Google hit for "JDBC connection timeout" by the way.

Comment: I thought this would be different from a connection timeout.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that it's a web application, I suppose you are using a DataSource provided by your container (Tomcat, JBoss AS, ...), right? Right?? :-)

If that's the case, then your container certainly has a way to configure this. For JBoss AS, this would be "blocking-timeout-millis".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I am using Geronimo application server. This does have a similar propoerty called blocking-timeout which is default to 5 seconds. altough this doesnt seem to have any effect. I have tried reducing to .5 seconds